# Como actualizo Codigo first entity framework desde base de datos?

Tags: entity-framework

Resulta que empece a hacer un modelo de base de datos a partir de code first entity framework y yo agregue una tabla en la base de datos con lo que quiero llevar ese cambio al code first. Se que puedo crear la clase en code first y con la migracion actualizarlo en la base de datos pero, quieo hacerlo de base de datos hacia el modelo code first cual seria el comando o la forma para realizar dicha ejecución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede hacer uso de wizard para crear el mapping Code Fist desde el modelo de tablas de la db

[Entity Framework Code First to an Existing Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx)

entre las opciones de wizard usarias `Code First from database`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

recuerda que el mapping que realizaste de forma custom puedes perderlo al ejecutar el wizard

Comment: Gracias me resolviste la pregunta